# RequireJS data-main called twice in Phonegap/Cordova platform Windows Phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, requirejs

I'm currently developping a Phonegap app with requireJS.
On iOS et Android platforms, my code is working just fine but on WP8 platform, the main.js file (data-main for requireJS) is called/executed twice.
And then it fires two deviceReady event and executing ajax requests, so this is not good !

I can't seem to find where is the problem.
Here is part of my code.

index.html

```
   <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script data-main="js/app/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/app',
     paths: {
         // Libs
         domReady:'../libs/require/domReady',
         jquery: '../libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min',
         knockout: '../libs/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.min',
         kopostbox: '../libs/knockout/knockout-postbox.min',
         sammy: '../libs/sammy/sammy.min',
         amplify: '../libs/amplify/amplify.min',
         moment: '../libs/moment/moment-2.6.0.min',
         underscore: '../libs/underscore/underscore',
         owlcarousel: '../libs/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min',
         viewport: '../libs/viewport/viewport.min',
         autosize: '../libs/autosize/jquery.autosize.min',
         imagesloaded: '../libs/imagesLoaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min',
         details: '../libs/details/jquery.details.min'
     },
     shim: {
         jquery: {
             exports: '$'
         },
         knockout: {
             exports: 'ko'
         },
         kopostbox: {
             deps: ['knockout']
         },
         sammy: {
             deps: ['jquery'],
             exports: 'Sammy'
         },
         amplify: {
             deps: ['jquery'],
             exports: 'amplify'
         },
         underscore: {
             exports: '_'
         },
         owlcarousel: {
             deps: ['jquery'],
             exports: 'owlcarousel'
         },
         viewport: {
             deps: ['jquery']
         },
         imagesloaded: {
             deps: ['jquery']
         },
         details: {
             deps: ['jquery']
         }
     }
 });

 require([
        'domReady',
        'app',
        'owlcarousel',
        'ko.customBindingHandlers',
        'viewport',
        'imagesloaded',
        'details'
    ],
    function(domReady, app){
        domReady(function () {
                app.initialize();
        });
  });
```

At first, I thought of a conflict with cordova but since it's working nicely in iOS and Android, I suppose it can't be.
I've tried removing the data-main attribut and inserting a script tag for main.js but it doesn't change a thing.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, please help !

Comment: Did you get any further with this problem?